# Как правильно написать: "количество выбранного наименования продукта"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать:
 1. количество выбранного наименования продукта
 2. количество выбранных позиций одного наименования
 3. количество продуктов одного наименования.

Какой из этих вариантов корректнее?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, наиболее удобоварим третий вариант.